# Rails. Simple form multipart file not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I use simple_form and multipart uploading does not work(uploading a single file works). Rails file_field_tag work...
Rails 3.2.13

```
<%= simple_form_for @building, input_html: {multipart: true} do |f| %>
...

  <%= f.simple_fields_for :paintings do |p| %>
    <%= p.input :image, as: :file %>
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 34):

You should use `html` option instead of `input_html`:

`<%= simple_form_for @building, html: {multipart: true} do |f| %>`